# Html5 dragenter event doesn't stop propagation?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to stop propagation of dragleave/dragenter event on nested elements, but it still firing in parent.
Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zD8w/2/). As you can see, mouseenter behaviour and dragenter behaviour differs, despite that the code is similar.
How to stop dragleave/dragenter propagation?

UPD. Seems like it's a bug of almost all browsers. Need to extend jquery.ui.mouse for correct behaviour.